# How to construct a dynamic xpath with regex pattern

Tags: regex

Pattern --> sometext + '(' + F|R|O|H|C + ')'

```
String toolTipTextLabel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'chartTooltip-label')]/descendant::bdi[contains(text(),'(F|R|O|H|C)')]")).getText();
```

Answer (score 2):

Xpath 1.0 **does not** support regular expressions.

XPath 2.0 [supports regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xpath.html) by using `matches()` function:

Your example: `/descendant::bdi[contains(matches(),'(F|R|O|H|C)')]")`

If you can't use Xpath 2.0 (and you probably can't because browsers don't support this) I would go with something like this:

```
String toolTipTextLabel;

List<WebElement> toolTipTextElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'chartTooltip-label')]/descendant::bdi"));

for (WebElement e : toolTipTextElements) {
   if (e.getText().matches("(F|R|O|H|C)")) {
      toolTipTextLabel = e.getText();
   }
}
```